# Could Whatsapp decrypt chats by sneak out private keys?

Tags: encryption, phone

The Whatsapp states that he doesn’t have access to users messages due to an encryption but the private keys are stored in there own app so could they just sneak out the keys from a phone and decrypt the chats?

Comment: I know nothing about that product, but yes, keys must always be secured carefully, because if they fall into an adversaries hands, the adversary can act as the legitimate user. Note however that decryption is handled by the receiving user (and encryption performed by the sender), so  the key you are worried about has likely been distributed to the authorized users, via some form of PKI.

Comment: Could you edit your post and clarify what you mean by the "green messenger"?

Comment: @FrankThomas I believe the premise of the question is that the app could secretly share end user's secrets with the infrastructure provider, therefore breaking the confidentiality of E2E encryption.

Comment: If the private keys are just stored in a file, they can be "sneaked out". On some platforms like Android there is the possibility to use a hardware backed key store for storing keys (not sure if Whatsapp uses it). If such a key store would be used key extraction would not be possible, however the messenger app could still provide a "decryption oracle" - received an encrypted key, decrypt it and send it back.

Comment: Yes, WhatsApp could get the keys if they wanted to.

Comment: ↑ Keep in mind that none of these issues is exclusive to Whatsapp. Try to stay impartial and apply the same skepticism to its competition.

Answer (score 0):

"Theoretically, yes", as they have full control of their source code. But I understand that you want a more *practical* answer, so I have to say:

**No, that's not how the encryption protocol used by Whatsapp works.** If they wanted to do that, they would have to fundamentally change their encryption system, and even if they surely COULD do that, such a huge code change wouldn't go unnoticed and would also invalidate their basic policies (privacy policy, agreements with users), bringing them legal trouble very very soon.

Here's how the Signal Encryption Protocol, used by Whatsapp, works - taken from [this article by Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/signal-encryption-protocol-hacker-lexicon/)

> The Signal protocol, however, uses a so-called "ratchet" system that changes the key after every message. It does this by generating a collection of temporary key pairs for each user, in addition to the permanent keys. When someone sends a message to a contact over an app using the Signal protocol, the app combines the temporary and permanent pairs of public and private keys for both users to create a shared secret key that's used to encrypt and decrypt that message. Since generating this secret key requires access to the users' private keys, it exists only on their two devices. And the Signal protocol's system of temporary keys—which it constantly replenishes for each user—allows it to generate a new shared key after every message.

So: any key they could "sneak out" would only decrypt one message, not a whole chat.

Moreover, the Signal Encryption Protocol is open source, meaning there's a vast community ensuring there's no bugs.

In such context, a man-in-the-middle attack, as your question implies, is unfeasible.

For anyone to read your WhatsApp messages, they need one of the following:

- physical access to your phone
- a backdoor to your phone, created
  by some malicious app
- access to your cloud backup, which could be
  not properly secured
- access through the Whatsapp Web interface. I
  guess such access could be hacked, even by WhatsApp themselves.
  Answering this would need more research which is outside the scope of
  your question.

In the end, your REAL question should be: "can I trust WhatsApp? e.g. can I trust facebook, a company known to not respect user privacy in any way?"

So, if you're involved in activities where privacy is crucial, you shouldn't use WhatsApp at all, but use other services which are dedicated to privacy, such as the Signal Messaging App